# Listing SQL Server Table Metadata

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to list all the tables in the SQL Server databases (all the databases) with their database name, schema name, table name, last create date, last insert date, last update date, last read date, last write date.

Can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: The table metadata is readily available in sys.tables. For the columns "last create date ,last insert data, last update date, last read date, last write date" you are out of luck. That information is not stored anywhere by default. Not really sure what you mean by "last create date". If that is the date the table was created it is also in sys.tables but if it is something else who knows what that means.

Comment: sys.tables will give me information about only single database. I want this information for all the databases present on that server. I want the list of the tables with their database names also.

Comment: Right. You have to start with a single database though. Start there and get the data you want. Then you can use a cursor and some dynamic sql to do this for all your databases. Or you can leverage sys.databases and dynamic sql to avoid the cursor. But regardless you have to write the query for a single database first.

Comment: https://youtu.be/z1HFiXt6KKQ

Comment: If that youtube video wasn't so horribly out of date it might be useful.

Comment: Below is the query i developed for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is available:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; select   name,create_date,modify_date from sys.objects where type=''U'''
```